# Laravel store user ip

Tags: php, laravel

**How can I store user ip in Laravel 5+**

I want store user `ip` when register:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function register(Request $request)
    {...

$input = $request->all();
$input['ip'] = $request->ip();
...
}
```

But this give me error:

```
message: "Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::ip() should not be called statically"
```

I googled but nothing found except changing `Request`, I tried `use Request` or etc.. but none of those solved my issue.

Comment: Please can you show your entire `register` method and/or where your calling `::ip()`.

Comment: Have you changed the code since getting the error mentioned in your question as what you have now should not throw that error (unless you're using `::ip()` somewhere else)?

Comment: Also, just an FYI, I wouldn't recommend returning a `200` response for failing validation as it's not successful. The default HTTP status code for failing validation with Laravel is `422`.

Comment: oh yes, I tried ip() again and it skip the error, but It didn't store ip yet

Comment: good point, I changed that

Comment: I believe you forget to add `ip` field to `$fillable`

Comment: Sidenote: In your `else` part the `if ($user)` part will never execute

Comment: @apokryfos why?

Comment: `if ($user)` is true then you return "Agent already exists" so it will never fall through to the else part

Comment: @Pedram oh yeah! it stored finally! but why stored like this ? (127.0.0.1) ? it stored my local host ip? why?

Comment: @apokryfos You right, it never execute `else` part, it should execute if user does not exists, so whats the point of this side note? have you any idea to improve this part? or is there anything wrong?

Comment: You can probably save a few lines of code using [`updateOrCreate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods) instead of having multiple if expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Laravel HTTP Requests**](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ip)

In `Request` class there is two method to get `ip`, first `ip()` then `ips()`. `ip()` return your `the client IP address`, there is no `getIp()` method. it return your `127.0.0.1` ip because you're trying to access your local project from the same machine.

**So:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
$input['ip'] = $request->ip();
```

And don't forget add `ip` to `$fillable` to your `model`:

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'ip',
    ];
```